# ラズパイより軽くて、無線接続できて、はんだづけが不要なものはないでしょうか？

Tags: raspberry-pi

もしわかる方いらっしゃいましたら回答いただけますと嬉しいです。

現状、ラズパイを使って、タクトスイッチ２つを付けて
２信号をPCに無線で送るような仕組みを作っています。

以下の機能だけでいいのでラズパイほどの機能は不要で
もっと軽量化したいと考えています。
何か他に良いシングルボードはないでしょうか。。。

■必須
・スイッチ２つを接続して２種類の信号を送れる
・無線（wifi, Bluetooth等）で上記の信号をPCに送れる

■可能であれば・・
・はんだづけ不要
・電池で電源供給できる

Comment: RasPi にもいくつか種類があるので、目安となる重量を書いた方が回答も付きやすいかと思います（電池に関してももう少し詳しい要件があった方がよいかなと）。

Comment: 小規模な回路に限ればブレッドボードを使うことではんだづけが不要になります([参考](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=44947))。現在はんだづけをする必要があるような回路構成なのでしょうか。

Comment: 「はんだ付け不要」というのがちょっとハードル高いです。完成品では少ないです。ESP8266、FlashAir などが候補になるかもしれません。ArduinoにもBluetoothに対応しているものがあったと思います。検索してみてください。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amazon Dash Button２個ではいかがでしょうか。
場違いな回答かもしれませんが、要件は満たしていると思います

リンク：Amazon Dash Buttonを(正しくない方向で)使ってみた
https://qiita.com/takustaqu/items/8539b33780c9675c8657

Comment: みなさま、回答ありがとうございます。いただいた情報確認してみます。今試していて重いと感じているのはラズパイ3です。

Answer (score 0):

現在 Raspberry Pi3 を使って機能要件を確認されていると言うことでしたら Raspberry Pi Zero が適当ではないかと思います。 何も変えることなく移行が可能です。

Answer (score 0):

Wio Node なんかはどうでしょうか。GROVE モジュールではんだ付け不要です。
https://www.switch-science.com/catalog/2799/

Answer (score 0):

M5STACKはいかがでしょうか。
初めからケースに入っていますし、その中に充電池も搭載されています。
別売りのバンドを付ければ、腕時計のように身につけることもできます。
Arduino IDE で開発できます。
https://www.switch-science.com/catalog/3647/